# Can one label vertices with attributes instead of integers?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm currently working on formalizing a graph for my master's thesis.
This isn't a question regarding the implementation of a graph, as I am already done with that part. My graph is an undirected tree where each vertex is unique and consists of a set of attributes. For example v1 contains the attributes (Id = 123, Name = Johnny, Weight = 70, etc).

I've tried to find research articles or journals regarding graph labelling vertices with a set of attributes instead of integers, but I cannot find any.

Does anyone know anything about this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: They can.  The details of how to do so depend on what graph library you use.  For boost::graph you want to look at "bundled properties"

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm working on my master's thesis - I am 100% done with the implementation of the graph, but I am working on formalizing the graph, that's where the issue lie. I am wondering how to formalize the attributes of the vertices, but I can't find any examples of people who have done it.

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  It doesn't seem like it is a question about programming at all.

Comment: I'll clarify the question, it's not about programming, but rather formalizing the problem using graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. A few ways to do so:

1. One definition of a graph is a pair (V, E) where V is a set of objects treated as nodes and E is a set of edges. You could just pick V to be the different sets of attributes - assuming none are repeated.
2. You could take your graph G = (V, E) and define a function f : V → S from nodes to a set S holding all your sets of attributes. Then f(v) gives the attributes associated with a given node.